# requirejs import losing mutation

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to use [jslogger](https://github.com/jonnyreeves/js-logger) with requirejs. I'm currently requiring the logger in my main.js

```
var logger = require('logger');
logger.useDefaults();
```

When I make logger a dependency on subsequent modules I would expect the "useDefaults()" mutation to persist...

```
define(['jquery','logger'], function($,logger) {

    // logger.useDefaults();
    logger.info("Doesn't log anything unless I uncomment line above");
...
```

However it doesn't log anything unless I apply the .useDefaults() within my module :-(

Am I doing something wrong... misunderstanding something?

Comment: When you require a module, requirejs will load the module again or take it from the cache if it is loaded already.
Requirejs exists to manage your dependencies and not maintain state of your modules.
Without requirejs, you would have to make sure logger.js was loaded before the modules that needed it in the html. That's all it does, it doesn't handle state.

Comment: OK great thanks for clearing up... I believe Browserify and Webpack both handle the module state and I assumed Requirejs did the same... looks like I need to switch to one of those :-)